# Where is the level being set for this Log4J code?

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following Log4J class :

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;

public class HelloWorldLog4J {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
    // private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("...Before");
        System.out.println();

        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message"); 
        logger.warn("Hello, this is an WARN  message");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is a FATAL  message");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is a FATAL  message ALSO, #2");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is a FATAL  message ALSO, #3");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is a FATAL  message ALSO, #4");
        logger.debug("Hello, this is a FATAL  message");
        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("...After");

    }

}
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
...Before

11:37:38.745 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is a FATAL  message
11:37:38.745 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is a FATAL  message ALSO, #2
11:37:38.745 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is a FATAL  message ALSO, #3
11:37:38.745 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is a FATAL  message ALSO, #4

...After
```

I've been looking for the Properties file(it's either log4j.properties or log4j.xml ) that determines my level here, but I don't know where to look for it. I read once that it's an environment variable, not sure how that works

I thought it might be in the directory of the java class (i.e HelloWorldLog4J ),  but it is not there.

EDIT: I run my code like this :

```
C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>java -cp C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-b
in\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar;C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4
j-core-2.0-beta5.jar;. HelloWorldLog4J
```

Where would the root of classpath be, if the root is a JAR file ?

Thanks

Comment: There doesn't need to be a property file; it will default. In any case, if there *is* a property file, it'll be at the root of the classpath unless specified to be elsewhere.

Comment: @DaveNewton - So  , by `root of the classpath` you mean the current directory ?  Ok , I'll try creating one there ( .properties file )

Comment: No, I mean the root of the classpath.

Comment: The root of the classpath is the union of the root directory of the log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar, the root directory of log4
j-core-2.0-beta5.jar, and the current directory (`.`), since those are the 3 entries of the classpath.

Answer (score 4):

Log4j 2.X follows this steps in order to configure itself:

- Log4j will inspect the `log4j.configurationFile` system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.
- If no system property is set the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for `log4j2-test.yaml` or `log4j2-test.yml` in the classpath.
- If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for `log4j2-test.json` or `log4j2-test.jsn` in the classpath.
- If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for `log4j2-test.xml` in the classpath.
- If a test file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for `log4j2.yaml` or `log4j2.yml` on the classpath.
- If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for `log4j2.json` or `log4j2.jsn` on the classpath.
- If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate `log4j2.xml` on the classpath.
- If no configuration file could be located the `DefaultConfiguration` will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

With your current configuration, you don't have any of these files, so Log4j is using `DefaultConfiguration`, that executes the following code:

```
public DefaultConfiguration() {

    setName(DEFAULT_NAME);
    final Layout layout = PatternLayout.createLayout("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n",
        null, null, null);
    final Appender appender = ConsoleAppender.createAppender(layout, null, "SYSTEM_OUT", "Console", "false",
        "true");
    appender.start();
    addAppender(appender);
    final LoggerConfig root = getRootLogger();
    root.addAppender(appender, null, null);

    final String levelName = PropertiesUtil.getProperties().getStringProperty(DEFAULT_LEVEL);
    final Level level = levelName != null && Level.valueOf(levelName) != null ?
        Level.valueOf(levelName) : Level.ERROR;
    root.setLevel(level);
}
```

So your logger has a Console appender, with ERROR level (so it only prints ERROR and FATAL messages) and the following pattern: `%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n`.

You can configure your logger programatically (like `DefaultConfiguration` is doing) or using any of the configuration files.

You have some example configuration files in this page:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

1. You are getting only *ERROR* level logs because by default log4net sets the root logger to level *ERROR*.  So basically you have no configuration at this point.

   > Note that by default Log4j assigns the root logger to Level.ERROR.
   >   https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html
2. Log4j2 looks for *log4j2.xml*.  Note the **2** in the name
3. Are you using a common IDE with a Maven build?  This is very common and if so try adding your log4j2.xml file to **${proj}/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml**.  This is the default Main "Application/Library resources" folder and will get deployed appropriately with most Maven JAR builds. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the log4j settings in multiple ways. It also depends if you are using log4j 1.x or 2.x

There is a very nice **Automatic Configuration** feature in log4j 2.x version.

```
1. Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will 
attempt to load the configuration using the ConfigurationFactory that matches the
file extension.
..
..
7. If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will 
 try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath .
```

Look for the simple **log4j2.xml** on the 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.INFO);

System.out.println("...Before");
//code ...
```

You can Modifying the level programmatically

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.TRACE);
```

see: [Set log4j log level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644687/set-log4j-log-level)